# How to flatten an array of nested objects in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-json

I have a rows that have json formatted as

```json
[{"FIRST": {"0": 1580, "1": 1745, "2": 2050, "3": 2395}}, {"SECOND": {"1": 1895, "2": 2431}}]
```

Because of the way the SQL was written there is only ever one toplevel key. I don't want to hardcode anything. I've tried a few solutions and they've led to me dropping values. I'm looking for a way to do this in pure Postgres that these objects get flattened and the array gets removed.

Expected output:

```json
{"FIRST": {"0": 1580, "1": 1745, "2": 2050, "3": 2395}, "SECOND": {"1": 1895, "2": 2431}}
```

Anyone have an idea how I could go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty simple with `jsonb_array_elements`, `jsonb_each` and `jsonb_object_agg`:

```
SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, value)
FROM example_table t,
jsonb_array_elements(t.json_col) AS elements(el),
jsonb_each(el) AS pairs(key, value)
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/37QAyk3s))</sup>

You'll want to either `GROUP BY` some row identifier or select only a single row with a `WHERE` clause. Alternatively use a subquery:

```
SELECT *, (
    SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, value)
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(t.json_col) AS elements(el),
    jsonb_each(el) AS pairs(key, value)
) AS new_object
FROM example_table t
```

Comment: So I might be a little slow here. So I can do `select id, jsonb_array_elements(a) from (values(1, '[{"FIRST": {"0": 1580, "1": 1745, "2": 2050, "3": 2395}}, {"SECOND": {"1": 1895, "2": 2431}}]'::jsonb)) s(id, a);` and that is giving me two rows of results. I make a temporary table `create temp table _json AS select id, a from (values(1, '[{"FIRST": {"0": 1580, "1": 1745, "2": 2050, "3": 2395}}, {"SECOND": {"1": 1895, "2": 2431}}]'::jsonb)) s(id, a);` and try to plug it into your code but it is telling me `"value" is ambiguous`.

Comment: So I only have one row in the table but when I do `SELECT * FROM _json t, jsonb_array_elements(t.a) el, jsonb_each(el)` I can see there are multiple `value` columns. This doesn't go away when I add a group by clause.

Comment: Ah, I had not considered that the default column name of the `jsonb_array_elements` result would be `value` as well. Disambiguating them with explicit aliases works though

Comment: Or [use the function names as aliases](https://dbfiddle.uk/MhsqUga-), but I don't think that's clean